# joining two queries via DB

Tags: sql, database, join

I have `2 queries` that work separately but I need to connect them so that the any users tagged with the `brand id 12` that are at `0` for `last used` comes into the list.

```
SELECT * FROM `brands` WHERE `id`='12'

SELECT * FROM `portal_users` WHERE `lastvisit` = '0'
```

I  looked on the internet but didn't  find a way to do this.

Comment: are the two tables brands and portal_users connected in any way?
How do you know a user is tagged with a brand?

Comment: Please post the create table SQL.  We need to see the columns on the table to join them for you.  Optionally you can just tell us how they are joined, e.g. brands.UserID = portal_users.UserID

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking for UNION:

```
SELECT * FROM brands WHERE id='12'
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM portal_users WHERE lastvisit = '0')
```

Answer (score 1):

Need more details in your question (table design, sample data)...

If the tables can be joined on a `user id` field, then something like this might work:

```
SELECT
   *
FROM 
   brands b

   INNER JOIN portal_users p
   ON b.user_id = p.user_id

WHERE 
       b.id='12'
   AND p.lastvisit = '0'
```